# Why does MSVC debug mode leave out the cmp/jcc for one empty if() body but not another (i++ vs. ++i)?

Tags: c, assembly, visual-c++, reverse-engineering

I'm using a AMD64 computer(Intel Pentium Gold 4415U) to compare some assembly instructions converted from C language(of course, exactly, disassembly).

With Windows 10, I used Visual Studio 2017(15.2) with their C compiler.
My example code is shown below:

```
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    if(++i == 4);
    if(i++ == 4);
    return 0;
}
```

The disassembly shows as below:

```
mov         eax,dword ptr [i]  // if (++i == 4);
inc         eax  
mov         dword ptr [i],eax  

mov         eax,dword ptr [i]  // if (i++ == 4);
mov         dword ptr [rbp+0D4h],eax    ; save old i to a temporary
mov         eax,dword ptr [i]  
inc         eax  
mov         dword ptr [i],eax  
cmp         dword ptr [rbp+0D4h],4      ; compare with previous i
jne         main+51h (07FF7DDBF3601h)  
mov         dword ptr [rbp+0D8h],1  
jmp         main+5Bh (07FF7DDBF360Bh)  
*mov         dword ptr [rbp+0D8h],0
```

07FF7DDBF3601 goes to the last line instruction(*).
07FF7DDBF360B goes to 'return 0;'.

In `if (++i == 4)`, the program doesn't observes whether 'added' i satisfies the condition.

However in `if (i++ == 4)`, the program saves the 'previous' i to the stack, and then does the increment. After, the program compare 'previous' i with the constant integer 4.

**What was the cause of the difference of two C codes? Is it just a compiler's mechanism? Will it be different with more complex code?**

I tried to find about this with Google, however I failed to find the origin of the difference. Have to I understand 'This is just a compiler behavior'?

Comment: Smells like optimization.

Comment: The code is equivalent to `return 0;` Anything else may be optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: except it's *not* optimized.  This is clearly un-optmized compiler output, which compiles each C statement separately, not doing any constant-propagation and effectively treating all locals as `volatile` so the program still works if a debugger *modifies* them.  Of course it can still optimize *within* a statement, and remove a jump over an empty `if` body.

Comment: Why are you looking at debug mode assembly? What insights are you trying to gain from this?

Comment: It isn't quite clear what he means. Of course they work differently, that's the reason why there are two operations. We don't need two operations that work the same, now do we?

Comment: Yes `++i` *sometimes can* be faster, but *debug mode assembly* is not exactly the right place to look for faster things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Paul says, the program has no observable side-effects, and with optimization enabled MSVC or any of the other major compilers (gcc/clang/ICC) will compile `main` to simply `xor eax,eax` / `ret`.

`i`'s value never escapes the function (not stored to a global or returned), so it can be optimized away entirely.  And even if it was, constant-propagation is trivial here.

---

It's just a quirk / implementation detail that MSVC's debug-mode anti-optimized code-gen decides not to emit a `cmp/jcc` over an empty `if` body; even in debug mode that wouldn't be helpful for debugging at all.  It would be a branch instruction that jumps to the same address it falls through to.

The point of debug-mode code is that you can single-step through *source lines*, and modify C variables with a debugger.  Not that the asm is a literal and faithful transliteration of C into asm.  (And also that the compiler generates it quickly, without spending any effort on quality, to speed up edit/compile/run cycles.)  [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point)

Exactly how braindead the compiler's code-gen is doesn't depend on any language rules; there are no actual standards that define what compilers have to do in debug-mode as far as actually using a branch instruction for an empty `if` body.

---

Apparently with your compiler version, the `i++` post-increment was enough to make the compiler forget that the loop body was empty?

**I can't reproduce your result with MSVC 19.0 or 19.10 [on the Godbolt compiler explorer, with 32 or 64-bit mode](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5HhYEA1AFsmsiAEp5HAOx8ADAEF5R%2BbIV5NAZgAi83Rwt7DxvADMI/fuftXv8gCxq9o7GJm54HryWPtb%2BgQ4cBiHEmARiLLZBCfraPgZSaozSAKxSpCzSuqWo0gDCETzywmISmlwWtKUEFfkFANYgFlwAdACctLojflwAbAActLQjFlpFhVJ%2BpeVSlaTVUqWCILqkXdv5pHCwMIgoqIoADngMmGQUEGgPTy8gwLMWpC4ngQXocIAAjbqkMGyJjEACe0g6pA%2BikwcgA8iwGAizqQsMo2M9IfhksgCHgAG6YQ64zAAD0wyBEwMRpVMmAYkIYeDBxFhcJqGEkUiRBGIeEUrIKzDYKHqjB5h1gLCYqJAYNQqEEBFIVOIiOmIx6u3u5NQLBpAFo6ch5Jb0bo7YpBnaAOpMBgMA6icSSWjS4qbSF7OmzaaW6Z%2BeTAZC22ZDCzyCC4QgkVrtUjyQWfZ7EdP%2BrP1TrdNR9AYWIazEbTIpcXRhkZFRZ%2BIrTNYbUiSvwjIa6OZaWZFEZaPy6XRaEdlYPSA5HE4li7XCBID6PXPkSirr765Ay35jgFAkGUCG46Eq%2BGs5F3VEYrE4nb41jAIm4kmM8lUmk7emM5nCpF2U5XFuV5flBSwK8xQlKVGGfOVeH4BUwSVKAVTVDUtR1PUDSNUsTTNC1pGtW17UdS13U9b1mj9AMpBKKdcRDMMIyjXdn3keNdF7JMUyIPNuAzLM7jXF50y4DQ6kQ3hizOfCEEwJgsH1dR21KSUim4pZaC4WhRy4IcRi4GZGJ2PZZ2OU5Knw/oLArFYii0NoRkHPwnKMttgIsIMmJnec5MXeBLhuLd1zeULvjwWNFnoQEGGBYhQVPHZz35K8UTRAhMWxYlMAJF9hUfPBSU/alIV/JkWRFNk5A5LkeT5eEIIAzpxUlarpXgzhpIEUDUIgdDJEw7VdW%2BEVDWNVBTTwc0rRtO0HTdD0vSEH0JDoOiGK2MzpFDcNIxMWN5EWXshloXj8H4/NM2zUSBLaCxJKLfzrLLOyEzsz6vq%2BtTOxATTTKqPzDkshdguXW4cxeDd3hE7cUAYRYAH061oIokZECwkcjQ94uPcFIVSy9quvRRbyy%2B9cvy18ipKykytpBlKpa8hauApFQMagUhSgtrYL3BC%2BF4ZD%2BsG9VNRGnDxrwgopsImlqN9Da1i26cpDpA7FEEClbQpE7HQgV0AEkADlsA0ZNLrTQT6GEqH7osAJCx62TXtIBSlO%2BVTgI7DTjm2oH9iEOcrONWyK2%2ByPPrWbzAd2PzQ/w4CuHUugDwD%2BOg8Tgo9UEGbyj8IA%3D%3D)**. (VS2015 or VS2017).  Or any other MSVC version.  I get no conditional branches at all from MSVC, ICC, or gcc.

MSVC does implement `i++` with an actual store to memory for the old value, like you show, though.  So terrible.  GCC `-O0` makes significantly more efficient debug-mode code.  Still pretty braindead of course, but within a single statement it's sometimes a lot less bad.

I *can* reproduce it with clang, though!  (But it branches for both `if`s):

```
# clang8.0 -O0
main:                                   # @main
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], 0       # default return value

        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 8], 0       # int i=0;

        mov     eax, dword ptr [rbp - 8]
        add     eax, 1
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 8], eax
        cmp     eax, 4                       # uses the i++ result still in a register
        jne     .LBB0_2                      # jump over if() body
        jmp     .LBB0_2                      # jump over else body, I think.
.LBB0_2:

        mov     eax, dword ptr [rbp - 8]
        mov     ecx, eax
        add     ecx, 1                       # i++ uses a 2nd register
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 8], ecx
        cmp     eax, 4
        jne     .LBB0_4
        jmp     .LBB0_4
.LBB0_4:

        xor     eax, eax                     # return 0

        pop     rbp                          # tear down stack frame.
        ret
```